# fix html Symbol Entities with php

Tags: php, html, symbols

I have one form for adding book to library (database) ...

Its my form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I use the form 'Words', the form will not be submited

I think i want this code in php :

```
str_replace("'", "&#39;", '".$_POST['title']."');
```

But it very very hard for all characters

Comment: need more in details.. "If I use the form 'Words', the form will not be submited" not understand

Comment: if i write this words: (',",.,...) fild not saved

Comment: what are you using to store data like mysql, mysqli or pdo?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp Would be useful

Comment: hi man, i really think if your problem will not solved using replace. Your problem is character encoding. You should use right encoding to do this. Maybe you can update your question with your word sample. I will give an example after i reach my office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this statement to replace all POST items

```
foreach ($_POST as &$post){
    $post = htmlentities($post, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Or use PDO quote method to escape the quotes

```
foreach ($_POST as &$post)
{
    $post = $your_pdo_connection->quote($post);
}
```

Comment: and how can i contrariwise use this?